# ¿Puedo crear nuevas clases gráficas con JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

Tenemos que crear un juego con su pertinente interfaz gráfica con JavaFX. Entonces, hemos decidido que primero se abrirá un menú para inicializar la partida (escoger número de jugadores, dificultad de jugadores CPU, etc...) pero, sobretodo, se debe abrir un fichero y luego, creada la partida, que se cierre ese menú y se pueda empezar a jugar usando los datos generados en el menú anterior (incluyendo el fichero leído, pero esa no es la pregunta).

Avisar de antemano que somos novatos en Java, es para un trabajo, y no nos enteramos de mucho xD. Entonces, disponemos de este código de ejemplo para abrir ficheros:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public final class FileChooserSample extends Application {

    private Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("File Chooser Sample");

        final FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

        final Button openButton = new Button("Open a Picture...");
        final Button openMultipleButton = new Button("Open Pictures...");

        openButton.setOnAction(
            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(final ActionEvent e) {
                    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
                    if (file != null) {
                        openFile(file);
                    }
                }
            });

        openMultipleButton.setOnAction(
            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(final ActionEvent e) {
                    List<File> list =
                        fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(stage);
                    if (list != null) {
                        for (File file : list) {
                            openFile(file);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


        final GridPane inputGridPane = new GridPane();

        GridPane.setConstraints(openButton, 0, 0);
        GridPane.setConstraints(openMultipleButton, 1, 0);
        inputGridPane.setHgap(6);
        inputGridPane.setVgap(6);
        inputGridPane.getChildren().addAll(openButton, openMultipleButton);

        final Pane rootGroup = new VBox(12);
        rootGroup.getChildren().addAll(inputGridPane);
        rootGroup.setPadding(new Insets(12, 12, 12, 12));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(rootGroup));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    private void openFile(File file) {
        try {
            desktop.open(file);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(
                FileChooserSample.class.getName()).log(
                    Level.SEVERE, null, ex
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Bien, nos lo hemos leído, nos hemos leído documentación de JavaFX, su estructura jerárquica, etc... Entonces, nosotros en nuestra APP tendremos un código de este estilo:

```
public class Partida extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stagePrincipal) {
        stagePrincipal.setTitle("CARCASSONE");

        ......
        stage.setScene(new Scene(...));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Es decir, nos gustaría poder separar todas estas `scene` del programa principal y llamar a su constructor desde la función `start` e ir añadiendolas (realmente sólo tendremos 2, el inicializador de la partida y la propia partida en sí, que esta sí seguramente la haremos dentro del propio main o aparte como `class Tablero` , ya se verá).

Así que, me he propuesto como problema didáctico separar el programa que he puesto al principio en una class main y en una classe de tipo scene que sirva para construir escenas para inicializar la partida. O debería ser de otro tipo esa clase? No sé, dejo lo que he intentado:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
public class GUI extends Scene {

    private Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    final FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    final Button openButton = new Button("Open a Picture...");

    public GUI() {

        openButton.setOnAction(
            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(final ActionEvent e) {
                    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
                    if (file != null) {
                        openFile(file);
                    }
                }
            });

        final GridPane inputGridPane = new GridPane();

        GridPane.setConstraints(openButton, 0, 0);
        inputGridPane.setHgap(6);
        inputGridPane.setVgap(6);
        inputGridPane.getChildren().addAll(openButton);

        final Pane rootGroup = new VBox(12);
        rootGroup.getChildren().addAll(inputGridPane);
        rootGroup.setPadding(new Insets(12, 12, 12, 12));
    }

    private void openFile(File file) {
        try {
            desktop.open(file);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(
                GUI.class.getName()).log(
                    Level.SEVERE, null, ex
                );
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yo le veo un problema a tu código, y es que usas `java.awt.Desktop`, esa clase es de awt. En java hay 3 APIs de interfaces graficas: awt, swing y javaFX. En swing se llegaron a usar eventos de awt para reutilizar código, pero en javaFX todo es nuevo, y no entiendo que intentas lograr poniendo componentes de awt en una aplicación javaFX.

Comment: El código original nos viene dado por el profesorado, aunque también nos han dado de ejemplo un juego de damas en el que un jugador puede hacer tiradas consecutivas infinitas si así lo desea... Indagaré sobre esto que me comentas.